# Scroll-to-top when element renders

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I am attempting to get the scroll-to-top function to work when a global error is rendered onscreen, which has an id of "globalError. I currently have a back-to-top function that is working great and was hoping to get help on getting this same function to work when a #globalError id is rendered, as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The back-top code I currently use:

```
// hide #back-top first
jq("#back-top").hide();

// fade in #back-top
jq(function() {
    jq(window).scroll(function() {
        if (jq(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            jq('#back-top').fadeIn();
        } else {
            jq('#back-top').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    // scroll body to 0px on click
    jq('#back-top a').click(function() {
        jq('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop : 0
        }, 800);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: how is the error inserted into the dom?

Comment: How/when are you rendering this `#global-error`element? Is it loaded with ajax? Or you just toggle between `display: none` and `display:block`?

Comment: We're using the ICEFaces framework. The global error element is an <ice:panelGroup> being rendered using the following rendered call: `rendered="#{facesUtils.existErrors()}`

Comment: Welp... Never heard of ICEFaces before, but maybe there's a callback or something to hook to? Worst case scenario, you could set an interval with something like this: `if ( $('#global-error').is(':visible') ) jq('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 0});`